# Agnostic Jew serving as the tenth for a minyan

Tags: halacha, tefilla, heterodox, minyan

I remember reading a responsum on the issue of agnostic Jew's serving as the tenth for a minyan, but do not remember the outcome. Does anyone know the rule?

Also, do we count, as the tenth man, a tinok shenishbah and one who does not understand the prayers at all?

- If it is permitted, would it be different for a lower level of chiyuve (obligation) for a minyan such as Maariv?
- If it is forbidden, would it be different for a higher level of chiyuve for a minyan such as Zimun, or someone who has a chiyuve for kaddish.

Comment: Igros Moshe OC 1:23

Comment: I doubt I'll get a response but is this question concerning an agnostic atheist or an agnostic theist?

Comment: I think I originally asked about atheists and someone changed the question, but this is a hypothetical (though common occurrence in many places I have been) so I would like to know opinions for both.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sam gave this source in a comment last year, but no-one ever came to post an answer, so i'll do that now...

In [Igrot Moshe OC 1:23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&st=&pgnum=66), he *paskens* that בשעת הדחק - in an emergency, someone who is publicly Mechallel Shabbat can be counted for a minyan, to say Barchu, Kadish, and Kedusha. However, for Torah reading, it is more important to have 10 religious Jews.

Comment: Two points. Reb Moshe was discussing a michalel shabbos as you mentioned and made a comparison to a kopher a point you left out which is probably important being that we can all be left wondering if an agnostic is comparable to a true kopher or a michalel shabbos. Second, are you sure he said what you wrote about Krias Hatorah?

Comment: Thank you, answer still does not refer to someone who does not know what he is answering as he does not know the language etc.