# Late kabbalat Shabbat with minyan?

Tags: tefillah-betzibbur, kabbalat-shabbat

If the only minyan for Kabbalat Shabbat/maariv davens two hours after tzeis (in the winter), is one required to wait to daven b'tzibur, or is there leniency to daven at tzeis without a minyan so that one can eat the seudah earlier - at 5:30PM rather than at 8:30PM (for example)?

This question is based within the position which forbids eating a meal before davening maariv. In other words, what is preferable, davening at tzeis alone and making the seuda as soon as possible, or waiting to daven b'tzibur, all the while allowing two hours of Shabbos to pass when one might be hungry and tired?

Comment: The minyan two hours after tzeis could be composed of mechallelei shabbos. Does this have a bearing?

Comment: (Some Poskim require one to pray alone any night in order to eat before Maariv. Most Poskim think Friday night is no different from other nights in terms of eating before Maariv.)

Comment: @BenjaminG This seems like just a question of how uncomfortable you have to make yourself it in order to daven with a minyan about which there is clearly no one size fits all answer. What is so unique about this circumstance that you expect something different?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Can you explain why the demographics of those davening matters - either on a weekday or on Shabbat?

Comment: @danf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27776/759

Comment: @BenjaminG How is this different from any other night of the week if you want to eat dinner at 6 and go to late Maariv at 9? That seems like a much more common scenario than a late Shabbat Minyan.

Comment: @DoubleAA in regards to your first comment, which poskim say that one should daven maariv without a minyan in order to eat? (and those that say friday is no different.)

Comment: @Double AA yes, this is my conclusion too.

Comment: @Dohble AA regarding what is unique about this situation: if a minyan davens late on Shabbos, it may be in order to accommodate those who drive or take public transit, whereas a weeknight late maariv is late in order to accommodate people's work schedules.

Comment: @BenjaminG Why might that difference matter?

Comment: @Double AA it has something to do with the kavana of the minyan aligning with the spirit of Shabbat and that there might be more room for leniency not to daven with the minyan if the kavana is contrary to the spirit of Shabbos. That said, this is very hard to quantify and really probably comes down to personal preference.